# Swift Beginner - Auto layout constraints (Xcode Interface Builder) question - is 'leading = label.leading' the same as 'label.leading = leading'

Tags: ios, swift, interface, interface-builder, swift5

Interface builder occasionally sets constraints for me, and it sets the main view's leading constraint to a label's leading constraint + an arbitrary number, let's say 30 for example with a view that has a top header label in the upper left corner.

Sometimes, when this happens, my constraints (at build time) seem to be off a little and interface builder just glitches like hell, preventing me from perfecting a view evenly, etc.

My question is, are these constraints (below) the same? What is the difference if there is one?

```
leading = label.leading
```

vs

```
label.leading = leading
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asserting that two values should wind up coinciding, and there is no ambiguity in your layout, then when all the constraints are resolved, those two values should coincide.

It doesn't matter if you say the superview's leading edge should match the labels's leading edge, or that the label's leading edge should match the superview's leading edge.  They mean the same thing.

If there is ambiguity in the layout, and the system tries to break that ambiguity, however, it might choose to resolve the ambiguity differently in either case.